# ¿Como crear un array dentro de otro array?

Tags: c++, array

Necesito saber como hacer una lista de listas, algo así como en python y los diccionarios, en donde te daban una entrada y te devolvía los valores. En otros ejemplo, algo como crear una lista de estudiantes y cada estudiante tiene sus su promedio A y su promedio B. (Alumno -- [promedioA , promedio B]. Con esos datos luego, según el input del usuario, imprimir el valor ya sea de promedioA o promedioB. Un input como:
input:
Alumno: Pedro

Output:
PromedioA: 15
PromedioB: 17

De mi programa intenté haciendo esto pero solo me da error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void azar(int planetas[]){

}
int main(){
    int planetas; int Mercurio[2] = {0.5, 0.3};
    int** sistema = new int*[planetas]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            sistema[i][j] = Mercurio;
            cout << sistema[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmmmm... `int Mercurio[2] = {0.5, 0.3};`: ¿`int` con `float`? Además, ¿y el `return` en el `main()`?

Comment: Por si a caso, `new` es para reservar una cantidad fija de memoria. No necesitas usar memoria dinámica directamente. Puedes crear un arreglo bidimensional cómo te sugiere una respuesta o usar [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @padaleiana el return no es necesario. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function#Explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un array de 2 dimensiones es en cierta forma un array dentro de otro. Cada posición del primer índice del array contiene un array dentro.

O sea, asumiendo var[x][y], por X = 0, hay una cantidad N posible para Y. X siendo una referencia al alumno y N siendo la cantidad de promedios para el alumno.

Saludos

Comment: Sí, tiene bastante sentido, intentaré hacerlo como dices, gracias.